# How to map json data coming from an REST-API to ember.js model?

Tags: json, rest, ember.js

I'm new to EmberJS and try to connect my EmberJS-frontend to an API via the RESTAdapter. I'm using ember-1.0.0-rc.6 and ember-data-latest (Version: v0.13-59-ge999edb).
From the API I get the following JSON code:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 5,
    "total": 4,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "something3",
            "description": "asd3"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "something3",
            "description": "asd3"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "something2",
            "description": "asd2"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "something",
            "description": "asd"
        }
    ]
}
```

My RESTAdapter looks like the following:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 13,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url:"http://localhost/api/app_dev.php"
    })
});
```

My model looks like this at the moment:

```
App.Modelname = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

With this I get the following error in the browser console:

*Assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key page but you have no mapping for it*

MY question is how to connect the json output from the api to my ember model without changing the api on the server?

Thanks in advance for your support !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is like this:

```
App.Modelname = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Then the `RESTAdapter` expects a JSON format like this:

```
{
  "modelNames": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "something3",
        "description": "asd3"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "something3",
        "description": "asd3"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "something2",
        "description": "asd2"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "something",
        "description": "asd"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can of course tweak some of this behavior by configuring some aspects of the `JSONSerializer` and the `RESTAdapter`, IMO to have full control I would suggest to create your own adapter by overriding the vital functions like `find`, `findAll` etc. and go with plain `$.ajax(...)`. Otherwise you would need to make your backend obey the JSON format ember-data expects.

Hope it helps, at least to take a decision.

Comment: Thank you for answer ! I'll try do write my own adapter.

Comment: @Oliver13, you are welcome, if you found my answer useful you could mark it  as answered for future folks stumbling upon this question.